# Will O3D take flash's place on the web?

Tags: flash, standards, o3d

O3D is a new google tech that enable 3D rendering within a browser (also 2D rendering), and if it is remotely like real 3D applications it is supposed to be capable of playing videos in the future!

[O3D on Google labs](http://code.google.com/apis/o3d/)

And flash every web-user and web-developer knows!

so what is going be the future of web? the new version of flash and it's new technology or O3D?

Comment: This question is too subjective to give a real answer to.

Comment: I'm asking about a overview based on what is happening right now! It is just to explore what people think about the new tech and how it will interfere with the standard one (flash)! also to think about how it's going to change (if) the future of web development for 3D apps! is it clear now?

Comment: I think that it would not be web 3D apps without windows vista/seven to push the hardware right?

Comment: This question is really not very useful.  You are comparing an asset production tool chain (the CS IDE), a virtual machine, a cross-platform rasteriser, a pixel shader middleware layer, two (3? haxe?) programming languages, a comprehensive RPC/Interoperability security model, a set of open standards, and a DOM (Scene Graph?) linked to an Event framework (That's what 'Flash' is) to a (at the moment) rudimentary 3D engine.

Comment: Not to mention all the other adobe products and interop tools (like RTMP / Edge Server)

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and say that no, O3D probably will not slay Flash, at least in its current incarnation.

The API is far less complete when compared to the breadth of ActionScript 3; it's still a third party plugin that needs to be installed; and Flash isn't just a video playback donkey.

That said, this is a pretty open-ended question.

Take a look at the Papervision 3 project that will be leveraging Flash Player 10's 3D functionality.

Comment: Papervision 3 is great but I think O3D is going to be faster (flash have a history of being slow on the user end...), and I think it can be a great solutions for 3D gaming on web. but the advertisement market and video market will most likely stay where they are right now! but enough about my opinion! hehe

Comment: I mean Papervision 3, the successor to Papervision 2.0 (Great White), not a type for Papervision 3D. I completely sympathize with performance issues with 3D in Flash, but by all accounts, the next version of PV3D will have significant performance and feature improvements.